# How to run a WordPress site across multiple ccTLDs?

Tags: multisite, seo

I currently have a site setup as a single installation under a **.com** TLD. I've been asked if we can set up a second version of the site – which will be almost identical, except for a few small details in the content – under the **.co.uk** ccTLD.

1. Should we look into setting up a WP MultiSite?
2. Are we better off running separate installations?
3. Am I correct in assuming this will have a negative effect on SEO, as the same (almost identical) content will exist across more than one domain?

Cheers,
Phil